# Encountering an error trying to run a file in matlab (OTB+ file, EMG Data) and supposedly turns it into

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm currently trying to decompose EMG signal using the MUEdit app (Can be found in https://github.com/simonavrillon/MUedit) and it fails to run my data due to different types of errors. I have a code that comes with the app and supposedly has to be able to turn the data for OTB+ file in a readable MATLAB structure.

I tried running the app after uploading the file but I'm encountering a lot of errors.

These are the errors

```
Unrecognized field name "Device".

Error in openOTBplus (line 16)
formatHDEMG.mFsample=str2num(abs.Device.Attributes.SampleFrequency);

Error in MUedit/StartButtonPushed (line 201)
                signal = openOTBplus(app.pathname, app.filename, parameters.ref_exist, parameters.nbelectrodes);

Error in appdesigner.internal.service.AppManagementService/executeCallback (line 138)
                callback(appOrUserComponent, event);

Error in matlab.apps.AppBase>@(source,event)executeCallback(appdesigner.internal.service.AppManagementService.instance(),app,callback,requiresEventData,event) (line 63)
            newCallback = @(source, event)executeCallback(appdesigner.internal.service.AppManagementService.instance(), ...
 
Error using matlab.ui.control.internal.controller.ComponentController/executeUserCallback
Error while evaluating Button PrivateButtonPushedFcn.
```

This is the code

```
function signal = OpenOTBplus(pathname, filename, ref_exist, nbelectrodes)
%Reads files of type OTB+, extrapolating the information on the signal,
%in turn uses the xml2struct function to read file.xml and allocate them in an easily readable Matlab  structure.
% Isn't possible to read OTB files because the internal structure of these
% files is different.

mkdir('tmpopen');
% cd('tempopen');

untar([pathname filename],'tmpopen');
% unzip([PATHNAME FILENAME]);
signals = dir(fullfile('tmpopen','*.sig'));

PowerSupply = 3.3;
abs = xml2struct(fullfile('.','tmpopen', [signals.name(1:end-4) '.xml']));
formatHDEMG.mFsample=str2num(abs.Device.Attributes.SampleFrequency);
nChannel=str2num(abs.Device.Attributes.DeviceTotalChannels);
nADBit=str2num(abs.Device.Attributes.ad_bits);

Gains = zeros(1,nChannel);
Adapter = zeros(1,nChannel);
for nChild = 1:length(abs.Device.Channels.Adapter)
localGain = str2num(abs.Device.Channels.Adapter{nChild}.Attributes.Gain);
startIndex = str2num(abs.Device.Channels.Adapter{nChild}.Attributes.ChannelStartIndex);

Channel = abs.Device.Channels.Adapter{nChild}.Channel;
Description = abs.Device.Channels.Adapter{nChild}.Attributes.Description;
Description = abs.Device.Channels.Adapter{nChild}.Attributes.Description;

if contains(Description,'bipolar')
    tempad = 1;
elseif contains(Description,'64')
    tempad = 2;
elseif contains(Description,'Splitter') 
    tempad = 2;
else
    tempad = 3;
end

for nChan=1:length(Channel)
    if iscell(Channel)
        ChannelAtt = Channel{nChan}.Attributes;
    elseif isstruct(Channel)
        ChannelAtt = Channel(nChan).Attributes;
    end
    idx = str2num(ChannelAtt.Index);
    Gains(startIndex+idx+1) = localGain;
    Adapter(startIndex+idx+1) = tempad;
    Grid{startIndex+idx+1} = ChannelAtt.ID;
    Muscle{startIndex+idx+1} = ChannelAtt.Muscle;
end
end

h=fopen(fullfile('tmpopen',signals.name),'r');
data=fread(h,[nChannel Inf], 'short'); 
fclose(h);

for nCh=1:nChannel
data(nCh,:) = data(nCh,:)*PowerSupply/(2^nADBit)*1000/Gains(nCh);
end

signal.data = data(Adapter == 2,:);
signal.auxiliary = data(Adapter == 3,:);

if ~isempty(data(Adapter < 2,:))
signal.bipolar = data(Adapter < 2,:);
end

nch = 1;
for i = 1:length(Grid)
if Adapter(i) == 2
    Grid2{nch} = Grid{i};
    Muscle2{nch} = Muscle{i};
    nch = nch + 1;
end
end
clearvars Grid Muscle
Grid = Grid2;
Muscle = Muscle2;


signal.fsamp=Fsample;
signal.nChan=nChannel;
signal.ngrid = floor(size(signal.data,1)/nbelectrodes);

for i=1:signal.ngrid
signal.gridname{i} = Grid{(i-1)*nbelectrodes+1};
signal.muscle{i} = Muscle{(i-1)*nbelectrodes+1};
end

% if the signals were recorded with a feedback generated by OTBiolab+,
% get the target and the path performed by the participant
if ref_exist == 1
target = dir(fullfile('tmpopen','*.sip'));
h=fopen(fullfile('tmpopen',target(2).name),'r');
data1=fread(h,[1 Inf],'float64');
fclose(h);
data1 = data1(1:size(data,2));
signal.path = data1;

h=fopen(fullfile('tmpopen',target(3).name),'r');
data2=fread(h,[1 Inf],'float64');
fclose(h);
data2 = data2(1:size(data,2));
signal.target = data2;
end
rmdir('tmpopen','s');
end
```

I'm not supposed to clarify the input of the variables asked in the function, because they should automatically be found after uploading the file in the app upon pressing "start".

Comment: As the code highlighting here already shows: `abs` is a built-in function. Shadowing it (using it as a variable name you defined yourself) might lead to obscure and hard to debug errors. I'd start with calling the thing something else. That said, can you `disp(abs)` after the line where you declare it (`abs = xml2struct(...)`)?  It appears that `abs` *is* a struct, but doesn't have a field called `Device`. `disp(abs)` would list all the fields it has.